# Scraping of broken html website

Tags: html, r, xpath

I am completely new to coding in R, and have been flung out into webscraping. 
I'm interested in scraping a list of 1012 links that look similar to this example: http://karakterstatistik.stads.ku.dk/Histogram/ASOB05038E/Summer-2015

So all elements are located the same places on all the links. However, using `SelectorGadget` for scraping does not work. I have alsp tried using xpath, but it is of no use:

```
library(xml2)
link = "http://karakterstatistik.stads.ku.dk/Histogram/ASOB05038E/Summer-2015"
link %>% 
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='karsumForm']/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]")
```

I get the error message:

> {xml_nodeset (0)}

Comment: you're not using `rselenium` though...

Comment: No I know but I used that for the list of links and I wondered if I could use it for scraping as well. Do you have a suggestion as to how to do it?

Comment: _technically_  that's not an error message. It's just the default print method for the `xml_nodeset` class letting you know that there are 0 elements in the  result value from the `html_nodes()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML isn't broken and you have to be careful when you try to come up with an XPath from the "Inspect Element" view since most browsers will normalize the HTML as they read it in. So Firefox, Chrome (et al) may show a nice `table > tbody > tr > ...` structure but the `tbody` tag may not be there on the page.

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://karakterstatistik.stads.ku.dk/Histogram/ASOB05038E/Summer-2015"

pg <- read_html(URL)

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//form[@id='karsumForm']/table/tr[8]/td[2]") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  trimws()
## [1] "115"
```

You can use `view-source` in most browsers to see the unadulterated HTML source or `devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/xmlview")` and do `xmlview::xml_view(pg)` on the `pg` in the code snippet above to see the raw HTML from the site (there's a mode in my `xmlview` package that lets you test out XPath filters, too).

If there are non-duplicated "named fields" then you can do something like:

```
get_val <- function(x, label) {
  xpath <- sprintf(".//table/tr/td[contains(., '%s')][1]/following-sibling::td", label)
  html_nodes(x, xpath=xpath) %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
}

get_val(pg, "Fakultet")
## [1] "Det Samfundsvidenskabelige Fakultet"

get_val(pg, "Institut")
## [1] "Sociologisk Institut"

get_val(pg, "Termin")
## [1] "s15"

get_val(pg, "ECTS")
## [1] "15"

get_val(pg, "Andre versioner") %>% gsub("[[:space:]]+", ", ", .)
## [1] "s16, v15, s14, s13, s12, s11"
```

You can somewhat deal with dups:

```
get_val(pg, "Antal tilmeldte")
## [1] "115"             ""                "Antal tilmeldte" "11"
```

but it may not be perfect.

You can get far more targeted if you hone your XPath skills (I won't be posting any more for this answer).

Comment: When I run the code you suggest I get this message in the console: 
    xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed character(0)
Warning message: 
In xpath_search(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns, num_results = Inf) :
  Invalid predicate [1206]
I can't quite figure out what's wrong with the code

Comment: I accidentally deleted the `]` (and fixed it)

Comment: Ah yeah it works now, thanks! However, when I look at what pg contains it gives me: 
>pg[1:10]
$node
<pointer: 0x1029c3650>

$doc
<pointer: 0x10291bca0>

$<NA>
NULL

And the last one continues down. I'm just wondering how I can scrape informations like which institute it is "Institut" and other things from pg?
Thanks for taking your time to answer me! :)